# Creating a backup of mapped drives on Windows XP

Tags: batch-file, drives

I need to create an application that will restore a user's mapped drives from a database. To do this, I need to create a script that will automatically back up the user's mapped drives on logon.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can write this backup to a text file using something like this:

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

type nul > C:\NetworkDriveList.txt

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%a in ('net use') do (
set line=%%a
if "%line:~0,2%" == "OK" echo !line:~13,2! !line~23! & echo !line:~23!>> C:\NetworkDriveList.txt
)
```

This will create a txt file with the share paths in it for future reference should you need them again.